# Is a CUDA kernel that contains __syncthreads() further limited in its block size?

Tags: cuda

Must a kernel that contains __syncthreads() have all its threads running concurrently at the time of the sync? If that is the case, how is it possible to use a larger block size than the number of concurrent threads?

Comment: Where did you come to the conclusion that it is "... possible to use a larger block size than the number of concurrent threads"?

Comment: Is it not possible then? If I have many threads running in the same block and I call __syncthreads(), my idea is that all threads must have completed their computation up to that point. If that's the case, they must be running concurrently. If they are running concurrently you couldn't have a block size greater than the maximum # of concurrent threads.

Comment: Also, why the down vote and close?

Comment: No it's not possible, and a short perusal of Appendix G of any version of the Programming guide will show you why - http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#features-and-technical-specifications

Comment: Thank you. Is what I'm saying correct about all threads in a block after __syncthreads() must be concurrent?

Comment: All threads in a block execute "concurrently" but not in lock-step. The lowest level of thread execution is the warp level, where groups of 32 threads *are* executing in lock-step. But different warps may be at different points in the instruction stream. However `__syncthreads()` is a barrier which states "all threads must meet this barrier before any thread is allowed to proceed beyond it." The threads arrive at the barrier warp-by-warp. Once all warps are at the barrier, then the SM scheduler is free to select one (or more) of those warps to execute the next instruction after the barrier.

Answer (score 3):

`__syncthreads()` is only a block-level barrier (read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions)) not a grid-wide, device-wide,  or "kernel-wide" barrier or sync point.

Therefore the only requirement is that all threads in a block are schedulable, and this is in fact a requirement for the block to launch on a SM, so there is no extra requirement needed to satisfy `__syncthreads()`, and it imposes no special limits on block size.

Comment: I get that it's only for blocks, I was unclear in my first sentence. Then how is a certain state in memory guaranteed if all threads in a block are not running concurrently after __syncthreads()?

Comment: I don't really understand this question "Then how is a certain state in memory guaranteed if all threads in a block are not running concurrently after __syncthreads()"  Where is it written that a certain state in memory is guaranteed?  Perhaps you're just struggling with the nature of execution of threadblocks at the warp level.